# How can I get the timezone my device in Google Assistant?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-developers-console, google-assist-api

I want to get the timezone of my device in Google Assistant. I have created the Google Action added DialogFlow as a Fulfillment tool.
Before the start to talk with the user I want to say Good morning/Hello/Good night, but for this action I need to get the timezone/time of the device from Dialogflow or Google Console or something like this one.
For example, in Amazon Alexa, to get the time zone, you just need to send a request with deviceId like '/v2/devices/ {deviceId>/settings/System.timeZone'.
Is it possible to do the same as Amazon Alexa or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform does not provide a way to get the timezone of the user or of a given device.